# Searching a Flask-SQLAlchemy database efficiently

Tags: sqlalchemy, full-text-search, flask-sqlalchemy

Currently, I am running the following code:

`User.query.filter(or_(User.username.contains(query), User.name.contains(query)))`

But naturally, when you're hitting a few million records and searching multiple columns the `LIKE "%query%"` starts to get expensive. `Whoosh` is heavily outdated, and `sqlalchemy-fulltext-search` does not seem to want to work with my Flask structures. Do I have any options left to consider, other than a switch to `PostgreSQL`?

Comment: What is wrong with `sqlalchemy-fulltext-search`?

Comment: checkout elasticsearch for (almost)real time query and efficiently searching:  https://www.elastic.co

Comment: There isn't much to go on here, but if you're scanning millions of records then it's critical that the relevant columns are indexed, and indexed with the right type of index.

Answer (score 0):

`Flask_sqlalchemy` is your ORM not your DBMS. You can use it **with** PostgreSQL as your database. 
How you query your database is what matters in your case.

### 1-use sqlalchemy core

`SQLAlchemy` lets you execute raw `SQL` commands so you can write your query commands yourself rather than using `Model.query.filter()`.
So one option is to write your `select expressions` yourself and more efficiently.

### 2-ELK

elastic search abstracts lots of efficient algorithms for you to use! 
you can rely on [elasticsearch](http://elastic.co) for searching your database.